# What's the best way to add a left margin to an NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to add a left hand margin to an NSAttributedString so that when I concatenate it with another NSAS, there is a bit of space between the two box frames.

All I have so far is this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *issn = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:jm.issn attributes:nil];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [issn length]);
[issn addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
             value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Medium" size:8]
             range:range];

NSMutableAttributedString *textLabel = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:title];
[textLabel  appendAttributedString:issn];
```

I want the margin on the left side of the second string.

Thanks!

Edit: image upload

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. How is the NSAS to be shown on the screen? What exactly does it look like and how do you want it to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a tab character between the two strings?

You could do this by changing your first line to this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *issn = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@", jm.issn] attributes:nil];
```

This should output something like like what you want. You may, however, want to add 2 `\t` characters instead of one because depending on the string length, it may not need a tab character to align it (for example, in that exact string you posted, it didn't add anything to my output).

1 tab with your string:

[image: One tab]

2 tabs with your string:

[image: Two tabs]

Comment: Thanks to everybody for your answers.  You are correct, there's no equivalent to the html span{display:inline-block} in the NSMutableAttributedString class.  I wish there was!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you're concatenating attributed strings then there is no "margin" around a specific range in the final string. How would that work with multiple lines or text wrapping?

If you want clear space within an attributed string, use white space characters - spaces or tabs. You can define the position of tab stops using paragraph styles.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is, add the required spaces(or whitespace characters) before the source string and then add it to your NSMutableAttributedString.

```
 NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", jm.issn] <- Have given two spaces here.
```

Thanks